# Ajax get caused in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I have two Ajax Get Request:

```
$.get('/tutorials/rate', {id: {{$tutorial->id}}}, function (data) {
    $ratingCount = data;
});

$.get('/tutorials/rateAverage', {id: {{$tutorial->id}}}, function (data) {
    $averageRating = data;
});
```

in my Controller:

```
public function get_rate()  {
    $postId = Input::get('id');
    $ratings = rating::where('tutorial_id', '=', $postId)->get();

    return count($ratings);
}

public function get_rateAverage(){
    $postId = Input::get('id');
}
```

in my routes:

```
Route::controller('tutorials', 'TutorialController');
```

First Request is workin like a charm, second one gives me a 500 Error...

Comment: Did you take a look at your server's logs ? It should tell you what happened.

Comment: Are you supposed to be returning something on the second request?

Comment: Yes i want to return sth, but thats not the reason i get the 500

Comment: Server gives me {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"\/Volumes\/Data\/Users\/Christian\/Downloads\/www-backup\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controllers\/Controller.php","line":290}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your second get request, try

```
$.get('/tutorials/rate-average', {id: {{$tutorial->id}}}, function (data) {
    $averageRating = data;
});
```

Your function names should be `getRate()` and `getRateAverage()`

This is what Laravel expects as far as naming conventions.  Please see http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: This works perfectly...THX! But why is the first one working?!

Comment: It looks as though Laravel will respond to `get_rate()` if `getRate()` does not exist.  The hyphen-notation is what caused the second method to break.